# VSCode terminal behaves strangely when opening a project that is inside WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl2

It is really nice how you can open a project that is meant to build in Linux inside WSL2 via VSCode. But the terminal is behaving different that if I where to run the same commands on WSL2. This are the steps I do to replicate my problem:

1. Open Ubuntu WSL2. This just opens a terminal that is running ubuntu
2. Navigate to the project I want to open `cd ~/myapp`
3. Open that project with vscode `code .` vscode opens in a linux enviroment. On the bottom left corner it shows "WSL:Ubuntu". It is really cool how I can open projects on linux just like if I where to be using a linux computer.
4. I open the terminal and I run this command `powershell.exe 'echo "hello-world"'`. I get the following error:

> <3>init: (5450) ERROR: UtilConnectToInteropServer:300: connect failed 2

If I open WSL2 and run the same command `powershell.exe 'echo "hello-world"'` it works. It just does not work if using vscode terminal. The strange thing is that it used to work. If I reboot my computer it starts working on vscode and eventually stops working. The solution is to use a separate WSL2 terminal. But it will be nice if I could use vscode integrated terminal.

Another solution will not to use powershell. But I need to use powershell because WSL2 does not have USB support. I am building an esp32 project. Once build I need to flash the code to my microcontroller. I have to do this via windows and that is the reason why I use powershell. I could also build my project on windows but I already have all the projects configured to compile and intellisense working on linux.

Comment: I've also noticed that this is the root cause for why Docker with WSL2 suddenly stops working with an error like `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally got it working. I added this to `~/.zshrc`. If you are using bash add it to `~/.bashrc`

```
fix_wsl2_interop() {
    for i in $(pstree -np -s $$ | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'); do
        if [[ -e "/run/WSL/${i}_interop" ]]; then
            export WSL_INTEROP=/run/WSL/${i}_interop
        fi
    done
}
```

If it stops working I just call that function.

I got that solution from this link: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5065

Comment: In my VS Code terminal, I often pipe output in to **clip.exe**, the Windows clipbaord. `echo "Tono Nam" | clip.exe` works again    Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent to @tono-nam 's bash/zsh fix for `pwsh`:

```
function Reset-WslInterop
{
    param ($ProcessId = $PID)

    if (Test-Path /run/WSL/$ProcessId`_interop)
    {
        $env:WSL_INTEROP="/run/WSL/$ProcessId`_interop"
        return
    }

    Reset-WslInterop (Get-Process -Id $ProcessId).Parent.Id
}
```